# Bots integration with TestFlight

Tags: ios, xcode, continuous-integration, testflight, xcode-bots

I'm trying to upload a build new created with the continuous integration system provided by Apple, Bots, to TestFlight. I have created an archive post-action in the scheme, but I don't know how to get the path to the build on post-action script. 
Does anybody know how were Bots saves the builds and how we get this path, to use it in scripts?

Thanks,
Mihai

Comment: The solution is APP="${BUILD_ROOT}/Debug-iphoneos/${FULL_PRODUCT_NAME}"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are all stored here: `/Library/Server/Xcode/Data/BotRuns`

Check out this other [post action script.](http://matt.vlasach.com/xcode-bots-hosted-git-repositories-and-automated-testflight-builds/)